# Is it possible to create show/hide on display inline-block without affecting neighboring elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle, css

I've created a demo of the problem I'm having: http://jsbin.com/omomit/2

When you click on show/hide link, you see the hidden text appear. The behavior I'd like to fix is how it pushes down both the 1st and 2nd row of content instead of just the parent container in which it exists.

In other words, if you label each list item, it would look like this:

A B         ( <---This is a faux-row, since it's not programmed to be a row)
C D

When I click on the toggle for A, it looks like this (H for hidden content):

A B
**H** _
C D

D has been pushed down and this shouldn't happen. Instead, I want it to be just this:

A B
**H** D
C

I know I can fix this using floats, but the reason I don't want to use floats is because these columns need to emulate a table so that, no matter the height of each faux-column module, they line up in the faux-row. It's critical that each faux-row align with each other from the top down, which is why I am also used vertical-align set to top.

Is it possible to have this toggle script functionality so that it only affects the parent container in which it's being used?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking for, but if you have the show/hide content inside of an element that is absolutely positioned, it won't affect the layout.

Try adding these CSS properties to your .hiddentoggle selector:

```
.hiddentoggle {
  display:none; // you already had this there
  background: lightBlue;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on your new information, I'm curious why you don't want to use floats. I'm also curious what you mean by "faux-row".

Either way, if you want only the C box to move down when showing the A content, the only way to make that happen is to wrap A and C in an element. That element doesn't have to be floated, it would also be `display:inline-block`, but however you decide to lay it out, you're going to need to make some sort of "column" in order to get the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added more info above to clarify what I'm looking for. Positioning absolute would not work because it overlays on top of the next module in the faux-column. The effect I'm going for is that the faux-column would move with the hidden div as it appears.

Comment: Basically, this is going to be a very symmetrical Menu page for food items. The client wants these rows to be aligned. If I float the different elements, and if one of those elements is longer than the others, the float might break. For instance, if A is much longer than B, C, and D, then A will line up with B and C will line up under B since it doesn't clear the float. That messes up the flow. Hopefully this makes sense.